# How to call objects from nested arrays

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Am looking to use a public [[api]](https://api.covid19api.com/all) for a personal project. This is a snippet of a full json data set.

```
"Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "ALA Aland Islands",
      "CountryCode": "AX",
      "Slug": "ala-aland-islands",
      "NewConfirmed": 0,
      "TotalConfirmed": 0,
      "NewDeaths": 0,
      "TotalDeaths": 0,
      "NewRecovered": 0,
      "TotalRecovered": 0,
      "Date": "2020-04-05T06:37:00Z"
    },
```

I've tried to access the object in the array, I even tried some answers I saw here, but it's not working for me either I keep getting my "loading data..." screen or I get a white screen with no errors.
My code snippet below

```dart
class CountriesData {
  String country;
  String countryCode;
  int confirmed;
  int deaths;
  int recovered;
  int active;
  DateTime date;

  CountriesData(this.country, this.countryCode, this.confirmed, this.deaths, 
      this.recovered, this.active, this.date);

  CountriesData.json(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['Country'];
    countryCode = json['CountryCode'];
    confirmed = json['Confirmed'];
    deaths = json['Deaths'];
    recovered = json['Recovered'];
    active = json['Active'];
    date = DateTime.parse(json['Date']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you never parsed the JSON. To use the values from JSON, you need to first convert to Map. You have to import `dart:convert` library and then you can use the function `json.decode(jsonData)`. This returns a map that you can use to fetch data from.

```
var jsonData = fetchJson();
var parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
var x = CountriesData.json(parsedJson);
```

Comment: am I supposed to create the method for the fetchJson(), cos it's throwing a create method error

Comment: No, that's just an example. Sorry if I wasn't clear